# Select value from an enumerated list in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.1

I want to select from an enumaration that is not in database.

E.g. `SELECT id FROM my_table` returns values like 1, 2, 3
I want to display `1 -> 'chocolate', 2 -> 'coconut', 3 -> 'pizza'` etc. `SELECT CASE` works but is too complicated and hard to overview for many values. I think of something like

```
SELECT id, array['chocolate','coconut','pizza'][id] FROM my_table
```

But I couldn't succeed with arrays. Is there an easy solution? So this is a simple query, not a plpgsql script or something like that.

Answer (score 10):

```
with food (fid, name) as (
  values 
     (1, 'chocolate'),
     (2, 'coconut'),
     (3, 'pizza')
)
select t.id, f.name
from my_table t
  join food f on f.fid = t.id;
```

or without a CTE (but using the same idea):

```
select t.id, f.name
from my_table t
  join (
     values 
       (1, 'chocolate'),
       (2, 'coconut'),
       (3, 'pizza')
  ) f (fid, name) on f.fid = t.id;
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the correct syntax:

```
SELECT id, (array['chocolate','coconut','pizza'])[id] FROM my_table
```

But you should create a referenced table with those values.

Comment: Thank you!!! This is the simple solution I was looking for and it works. Just the parentheses were missing. (I already told once that I don't want to create a table because database is not mine and this is a casual query, but somebody deleted that answer with my comment.)

Answer (score 0):

What about creating another table that enumerate all cases, and do join ?

```
CREATE TABLE table_case
(
  case_id bigserial NOT NULL,
  case_name character varying,
  CONSTRAINT table_case_pkey PRIMARY KEY (case_id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

and when you select from your table:

```
SELECT id, case_name FROM my_table 
inner join table_case on case_id=my_table_id;
```